# Best way to pass current Django view's name into the template?

Tags: django, view

Suppose I have a view handler like this:

```
@require_GET
def FooView(request):
  # do stuff...
  return render_to_response(
    'foo.html',
    {
      # some data...
      'current_view': 'FooView' # the eyesore
    }
  )
```

I need the 'current_view' value for marking the current menu item, breadcrumbs, etc.

Is there an easy / established way to make the current view name available to the template?

Of course I can construct a per-view class and use `self.__class_.__name__` or something; I'm interested in an easy and *established, Django-idiomatic* way, it it exists.

I'm using Django 1.4.

Comment: Class based generic views should automatically add a `view` variable to the context that points to the `View` instance. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data And if all else fails, you can just add your own variable in `get_context_data`

Comment: @Ngenator: thanks, it's nice, but I'm stuck with Django 1.4 for now. (Updated my question.)

Comment: Maybe context_processors?

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: I'm fine with writing my own context processor. Is there a standard one doing that already? The default ones don't seem to (or I'm missing something).

Comment: More than the view name, would it not make sense to split the URL or have some alternative way ? [Here](http://blog.isotoma.com/2009/12/getting-the-name-of-the-current-view-in-a-django-template/) is one way of accessing the view name in the template

Comment: @karthikr: Though your link shows a clever solution, I'm afraid looking up stack frames is not what I'd call established or idiomatic :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Context Processor to fill this information and have it automatically in all you templates

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve


def custom_context_processor(request):
    return {'view_name': resolve(request.path)[0]}
```

you can than add this context processor in your settings to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple. That way you can access it in every templates like in the following snippet :

```
{{ view_name }}
```